Error fetching user: [TypeError: 0, _jwtDecode.default is not a function (it is undefined)]
This is the code for my index.js file in react native where im trying to fetch the userID if the currently logged in user.
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode"; // Ensure this is correctly imported
import axios from "axios";

const index = () => {
  const [userId, setUserId] = useState("");
  const [user, setUser] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUser = async () => {
      try {
        const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("authToken");
        if (!token) {
          console.log("No token found");
          return;
        }
        console.log("Token retrieved:", token);

        const decodedToken = jwt_decode(token);
        console.log("Decoded token:", decodedToken);

        const userId = decodedToken.userId;
        if (!userId) {
          console.log("No userId in token");
          return;
        }
        setUserId(userId);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error fetching user:", error);
      }
    };
    fetchUser();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("userId:", userId);
  }, [userId]);

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>index</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default index;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});


it gives me these logs:

LOG  userId:
LOG  Token retrieved:
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiI2NjdhYWEyODhlOWZiNTAxMDExMmQwNTIiLCJpYXQiOjE3MTk0ODIzMTl9.RB6ZVFQRv8Q2s_zrKljEUQP1EKt42Od7qyHZjTGOZAU
LOG  Error fetching user: [TypeError: 0, _jwtDecode.default is not a
function (it is undefined)]

I tried reinstalling jet-decode using rpm but it didnt help.

Not sure if this is relevant - the docs show the import line as: import { jwtDecode } from "jwt-decode";

did that but didn't help
